# CubeMX + I2C + датчик TC74

Tags: stm32

Я пробую подсоединить датчик температуры TC74 к плате STM32L152-Nucleo. Нашел в библиотеке STM32CubeL1 LL-проект и попробовал переделать его под себя. Но в результате получаю на logic analyzer, что после отправки адреса датчику ( слейв ), линия SCL находится в постоянном нуле, а линия SDA в постоянной единице.

Насколько я понял, в интернете это известная проблема. Что я делаю не так ? Как мне сгенерировать в CubeMX рабочий код под мой датчик ?

Comment: А вы пробовали отправить адрес без подключения датчика? Та же ситуация будет? На самом деле должно быть наоборот: при подключённом датчике как только он принял свой адрес, он должен удержать линию SDA на нуле, а SCL должен подняться.

Answer (score 0):

После отправки адреса датчик должен отправить ACK. Вы в свою очередь должны провести проверку EV6 исходя из документа RM0008 (Figure 273, Figure 274). Если в течении некоторого времени событие не происходит, значит отправка адреса провалена и вы должны установить регистр CR1->PE в состояние RESET.

Если EV6 не проходит, то скорее всего вы не правильно отсылаете адрес или он неверен. Попробуйте сдвинуть адрес на один бит влево (address << 1).

Так же я бы порекомендовал попробовать использовать hal и Atollic TrueSTUDIO for STM32 (в данный момент ide пренадлежит STMicroelectronics) и CubeMX поддерживает генерацию проектов под эту среду.